# XSLT transformation for Word

Tags: c#, xslt, ms-word

I'm writing a web service in .NET C# that takes in an object, converts it to xml, applies an XSLT template, runs the transformation, and returns an MS work file.

Here is the code for the function:

```
public static HttpResponseMessage Transform(object data)
{
    var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter);

    var applicationDirectory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    var xsltPath = applicationDirectory + @"\Reporting\Files\Template.xslt";
    var templatePath = applicationDirectory + @"\Reporting\Files\Template.docx";

    var xmlObject = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(data.GetType());
    MemoryStream stream;
    using (stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        var sw = new StreamWriter(stream);
        xmlObject.Serialize(stream, data);
        stream.Position = 0;


        XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
        transform.Load(xsltPath);

        using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stream))
        {
            transform.Transform(xmlReader, xmlWriter);

            XmlDocument newWordContent = new XmlDocument();
            newWordContent.LoadXml(stringWriter.ToString());

            var outputPath = applicationDirectory + @"\Reporting\Temp\temp.docx";

            System.IO.File.Copy(templatePath, outputPath, true);

            using (WordprocessingDocument output = WordprocessingDocument.Open(outputPath, true))
            {
                Body updatedBodyContent = new Body(newWordContent.DocumentElement.InnerXml);

                output.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body = updatedBodyContent;

                output.MainDocumentPart.Document.Save();
            }

            response.Content = new StreamContent(new FileStream(outputPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read));
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new System.Net.Http.Headers.ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = outputPath;
        }
    }
    return response;
}
```

When I make a request, it gives me a word file without the data.

I put a breakpoint at using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(stream)).
After running that line, xmlReader has a value of {None}.

I'm also trying to avoid creating an XML file for efficiency(Hence MemoryStream).

Any idea why this isn't working? And is there a better way of accomplishing this?

Thanks,
Gerson

Comment: For testing purposes, if you save it to a file and then process it with the same code, does it work?

Comment: I think an XmlReader string value of `None` is to be expected and probably not an indication of a problem. What is the value of `newWordContent.InnerXml`? And are you sure that `newWordContent.DocumentElement.InnerXml` is what you want to use?  That will cause the outer element of the transformed XML to be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you change this:

```
   Body updatedBodyContent = new Body(newWordContent.DocumentElement.InnerXml);
```

to this:

```
   Body updatedBodyContent = new Body(newWordContent.InnerXml);
```

or this:

```
   Body updatedBodyContent = new Body(newWordContent.DocumentElement.OuterXml);
```

The way you have it there would cause the outer element of the transformed XML to be omitted, and I doubt that's what you want (though can't say for sure because you've shown us neither the input XML or the XSLT.